# How to get realtime data from database using jQuery every 1 second

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database

How to get **realtime** data from mySQL database using jQuery every **One** second

i need change document.write so i see result in new page

```
<SCRIPT>
            setTimeout("document.write('<p><?php
        $qry = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(clicks) AS total FROM short_urls');
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
        echo number_format($row['total']); ?></p>')",1000);
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Please, make sure you really understand why the code above is a total nonsense. You except the browser to run code that is designed to run on your server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple strategy is to use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout( function(){
  your_function_that_gets_data();
  your_function_that_displays_data();
}, 1000 );
```

For more sophisticated approaches, you might look into [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code).

---

**Update:** Anas, it looks like you went off the rails a bit after I suggested the above option. Whether you use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, you certainly want to avoid the confusing mix with which you updated your question.

Make a php page that simply returns the total. Write your JavaScript to call that page asynchronously (i.e., via ajax), at whatever interval you like. When the result is returned, use a callback function to redraw the page region so the total is updated for the user.

Something like this:

```
var updateTotal = function () {
  $.get('your_script_that_returns_a_total.php', function( data ){ // get new total
    $('#div_displaying_total').val( data ); // paint a div with the new result
  });
};
```

Now you have a simple function that, when run, will update a div in your view with the current total. Run that function as frequently as you like. For example, to run it every five seconds:

```
var running = setInterval( updateTotal, 5000 );
```

You can of course get much fancier with timing, writing your `updateTotal` function to call itself after a delay, etc. And you can stop the updating like this:

```
clearInterval( running );
```

...which allows you to easily set up an on/off switch.

If any of this leads to greater clarity, I'd suggest updating your question, which is attracting downvotes for the muddled code therein.

Comment: You might also want to consider setInterval(). It repeats it automatically. And to prevent to many requests at a time you should put a setTimeout at the end of the return of each request.

Comment: How is this code for streamlining, I mean will this clog up my server requests ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use PHP to make a call to the database to read all the rows out of it. The PHP would be called by an AJAX event set using a JavaScript `setTimeout()` function for every 1000ms (1 second). The huuuuge issue I can see with this is if you have many users, a large database and lots of simultaneous logins, you will very quickly overload your server. I think submitting a request every 30 seconds or something would be better, maybe 10 at the least.

Comment: thank you.. i will add this code in "About" page i think This will not hurt much because the number of visited this page a little

Comment: A nice idea, although just to be safe I'd only update at minimum every 10 seconds.